# Run cron jobs in different TZs

Tags: debian, cron

I have several cron events that need to run but on different timezones.  For example, I have one event that runs every day at 08:30 UTC, and another event that runs every day at 09:30 CET. I've read some articles that the timezone can be set in crontab by setting `TZ=CET` before the command, but I'm guessing that doesn't tell Cron what time the following event time is set at.  Is it even possible?  The server is running Debian with a system timezone in UTC.

```
TZ=CET
* 13    * * *   root    date >> ~/date.log
```

I've also tried `CRON_TZ=CET` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

```
TZ=CET
```

at the top of your `crontab` will set the time zone for jobs run from cron but won't affect `cron`'s interpretation of times for when jobs start.

If you want to set the time zone for `cron` as a whole then adding

```
export TZ=CET
```

to `/etc/sysconfig/crond` (or wherever the equivalent config is for your distribution) should change `cron`'s idea of time. You just need to find the config file which is sourced by the init script that starts `cron`.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/54364/how-do-you-set-the-timezone-for-crontab for more discussion of this.

If you just need to set `TZ` for particular jobs then set it at the start of the command. For example ...

```
*/1 * * * *       TZ=Japan date >> date.log
*/1 * * * *       TZ=CET date >> date.log
*/1 * * * *       date >> date.log

nph9@goat$ cat date.log
Mon May 11 22:34:01 JST 2015
Mon May 11 14:34:01 BST 2015
Mon May 11 15:34:01 CEST 2015
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. The problem is I have some events that need to run in CET and others that need to run UTC

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear on my objectives.

Comment: See updated answer  - that should do what you need using standard shell syntax

Comment: Much better title :)